# List queries 20 times faster than IQueryable?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, list, iqueryable

Here is a test that i have setup this evening. It was made to prove something different, but the outcome was not quite as i expected.

I'm running a test with 10000 random queries on an IQueryable and while testing i found out that if i do the same on a List, my test is 20 times faster.

See below. My CarBrandManager.GetList originally returns an IQueryable, but now i first issue a ToList(), and then it's way faster.

Can anyone tell me something about why i see this big difference?

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

int queries = 10000;

//IQueryable<Model.CarBrand> carBrands = CarBrandManager.GetList(context);
List<Model.CarBrand> carBrands = CarBrandManager.GetList(context).ToList();

Random random = new Random();
int randomChar = 65;

for (int i = 0; i < queries; i++)
{
    randomChar = random.Next(65, 90);
    Model.CarBrand carBrand = carBrands.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(((char)randomChar).ToString())).FirstOrDefault();
}

sw.Stop();
lblStopWatch.Text = String.Format("Queries: {0} Elapsed ticks: {1}", queries, sw.ElapsedTicks);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are potentially two issues at play here. First: It's not obvious what type of collection is returned from `GetList(context)`, apart from the knowledge that it implements `IQueryable`. That means when you evaluate the result, it could very well be creating an SQL query, sending that query to a database, and materializing the result into objects. Or it could be parsing an XML file. Or downloading an RSS feed or invoking an OData endpoint on the internet. These would obviously take more time than simply filtering a short list in memory. (After all, how many car brands can there really be?)

But let's suppose that the implementation it returns is actually a `List`, and therefore the only difference you're testing is whether it's cast as an `IEnumerable` or as an `IQueryable`. Compare the method signatures on the [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) class's extension methods with those on [`Queryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.aspx). When you treat the list as an IQueryable, you are passing in `Expression`s, which need to be evaluated, rather than just `Func`s which can be run directly.

When you're using a custom LINQ provider like Entity Framework, this gives the framework the ability to evaluate the actual expression trees and produce a SQL query and materialization plan from them. However, LINQ to Objects just wants to evaluate the lambda expressions in-memory, so it has to either use reflection or compile the expressions into `Func`s, both of which have a large performance hit associated with them.

You may be tempted to just call `.ToList()` or `.AsEnumerable()` on the result set to force it to use `Func`s, but from an [information hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) perspective this would be a mistake. You would be assuming that you know that the data returned from the `GetList(context)` method is some kind of in-memory object. That may be the case at the moment, or it may not. Regardless, it's not part of the *contract* that is defined for the `GetList(context)` method, and therefore you cannot assume it will always be that way. You have to assume that the type you get back could very well be something that you can query. And even though there are probably only a dozen car brands to search through at the moment, it's possible that some day there will be thousands (I'm talking in terms of programming practice here, not necessarily saying this is the case with the car industry). So you shouldn't assume that it will always be faster to download the entire list of cars and filter them in memory, even if that happens to be the case right now.

If the `CarBrandManager.GetList(context)` might return an object backed by a custom LINQ provider (like an Entity Framework collection), then you probably want to leave the data cast as an IQueryable: even though your benchmark shows it being 20 times faster to use a list, that difference is so small that no user is ever going to be able to tell the difference. You may one day see performance gains of several orders of magnitude by calling `.Where().Take().Skip()` and only loading the data you really need from the data store, whereas you'd end up loading the whole table into your system's memory if you call `.ToList()` on right off the bat.

However, if you *know* that `CarBrandManager.GetList(context)` will always return an in-memory list (as the name implies), it should be changed to return an `IEnumerable<Model.CarBrand>` instead of an `IQueryable<Model.CarBrand>`. Or, if you're on .NET 4.5, perhaps an `IReadOnlyList<Model.CarBrand>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<Model.CarBrand>`, depending on what contract you're willing to force your `CarManager` to abide by.

Comment: Can you show me what i should do to improve performance when working with the IQueryable in my example?

Comment: @TysHTTP: I added a couple of paragraphs. Does that answer your question sufficiently?

Comment: Thanks for your help! This list of car brands is mostly used as a master data list that is needed in memory when running another query that needs to look up records from this list (sometimes over 100.000 times per run). From what you are saying, i guess i should switch to IEnumerable?

Comment: @TysHTTP: Yes, if you know that you're not planning to have this list be backed by a LINQ provider at some point, it makes much more sense to just have it return an `IEnumerable<>`.

Comment: Keep in mind that he's also iterating the resulting query 10,000 times!  If it's a database query that's executed from the IQueryable that's 10,000 database queries, as opposed to just iterating an in-memory list 10,000 times.  If you only iterate the query once then it will very possibly be *more* expensive to call `ToList` than to just iterate it directly.

Comment: I thought that when i first force my IQueryable with a .ToList() , i'd get everything in memory. Like this: IQueryable<Model.CarBrand> carBrands = CarBrandManager.GetList(context).ToList().AsQueryable();   But that doesn't make any difference..

Comment: @Servy: I was assuming that the 10,000 iterations were purely for the sake of testing the speed of this operation. If the real code actually looked like his test code, it would certainly be faster to pull the items out into a List than to access a database. I do get the impression, though, that the `IQueryable` is actually backed by a `List`, so creating a copy of that list isn't going to make any difference compared with casting the existing `List` as an `IEnumerable<>`.